# Does Google Fused Location need internet access to provide a network location?

Tags: java, android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have a scenario in which our location providing app runs within a closed APN i.e not an open internet connection. When i set my device to only use the network location provider (Not GPS or even WiFi) i cannot get a location fix. The same code and scenario works perfectly if i'm on an open internet connection, off the APN.

So i'd like to verify if the Google Fused Location provider service needs to access the internet (Google servers perhaps?) in order to give me a location or whether the cell triangulation is done solely on the cellular network providers side.